# How to get only list of IDs from MongoDB using springboot?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query

```
@Query(value="{ 'studentsList.$id': ?0 }", fields="{'$id': 1}")
List<Subject> findAllByStudentID(ObjectId studentId);
```

I am trying to find a way to make this work. I know it currently returns the object with just the "id" field filled in, but I would like it to just return the ObjectID.

I know I could set the method to return a String and then convert it to ObjectID if necessary, but is there really no way to do this?

Comment: you need to use projection as options in the query https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/java/sync/current/usage-examples/find/

Comment: @TobokSitanggang But can I use the "projection" inside a Query annotation? I know I can use an aggregation but for something so simple I don't know if it would be a good practise.

Comment: in operation `find`, use `projection`. and in operation `agregation` use `$project`. there is different.